# Unable to import ldif file with some attributes

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, directoryservices, apacheds

I am new to ldap and apacheds. I have created embedded LDAP server using apacheds. Example [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/sandbox/kayyagari/embedded-sample-trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/directory/seserver/EmbeddedADSVerTrunk.java). But seeing the following issue. Am I creating a wrong partition? How would it look like? Any changes to ldif file?

**ERROR I am seeing when importing ldif file:**

> org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapNoSuchAttributeException:
>   ERR_04269 ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID samaccountname does not exist!

**Ldif file:**

```
dn: cn=Foo Bar,ou=people,o=foo,cn=ldaplookup,ou=dev,dc=foo,dc=bar
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Foo Bar
sn: foo_bar
givenName: Foo
name: Foo Bar
displayName: Foo, Bar
sAMAccountName: foo_bar
userPrincipalName: foo_bar@foo.chicago.com
mail: mail_foo@foo.com
```

**Additional ERROR when service starts up:**

```
11:19:12.622 [ATDD] [main] ERROR o.a.d.s.c.p.i.b.AbstractBTreePartition - ATDD - Cannot initialize the index for AttributeType userprincipalname, this value does not exist
11:19:12.622 [ATDD] [main] ERROR o.a.d.s.c.p.i.b.AbstractBTreePartition - ATDD - Cannot initialize the index for AttributeType user, this value does not exist
11:19:12.622 [ATDD] [main] ERROR o.a.d.s.c.p.i.b.AbstractBTreePartition - ATDD - Cannot initialize the index for AttributeType samaccountname, this value does not exist
```

Comment: Verify that the LDAP Directory Server targeted by the LDAP client has the required attributes defined in the schema.

Comment: How can I defined attributes in LDAP DS? I have following in my server code which I think sets the attribute. addIndex(cmePartition, "objectClass", "o", "ou", "uid");

Comment: Step 1: add attribute type Step 2: add attribute and value to existing entry. The attribute type defines the attribute, its characteristics and parameters, and must be accomplished before adding an attribute to an entry. Think of step 1 as configuration and step 2 as provisioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the schema, because in

```
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
```

is not define the samaccountname, so add the attribute, or schema..i thinks samba.schema

Comment: Didn't know about different schemas (e.g.: samba.schema). Will look into how to configure this in my server. Thanks!

Comment: the error says that you haven't this attribute defined in some objectclass